# Nested locks of the same Thread causing a dead lock

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, deadlock, thread-lock

I have a small class (`Counters`) which wraps a dictionary of objects (`Counter`).

Here is a simplified example (with my debugging prints...)

```
import threading
import time
import logging
import random

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='(%(threadName)-9s) %(message)s',)
                    
class Counter(object):
    
    def __init__(self, start : int = 0):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.value = start
        
    def increment(self):
        logging.debug('Waiting inc - %s', threading.current_thread().name)
        self.lock.acquire()
        try:
            logging.debug('Acquired inc - %s', threading.current_thread().name)
            self.value = self.value + 1
        finally:
            logging.debug('Released inc - %s', threading.current_thread().name)
            self.lock.release()
            
    def lastValue(self) -> str:
        logging.debug('Waiting lastValue - %s', threading.current_thread().name)
        self.lock.acquire()
        try:
            # return the last seen time in mysql format:
            logging.debug('Acquired lastValue - %s', threading.current_thread().name)
            return f" value -> {self.value}"
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)
        finally:
            logging.debug('Released lastValue - %s', threading.current_thread().name)
            self.lock.release()
            
    def getAsDict(self, with_log=False) -> dict:
        logging.debug('Waiting getAsDict - %s', threading.current_thread().name)
        self.lock.acquire()
        try:
            logging.debug('Acquired getAsDict - %s', threading.current_thread().name)
            return {
                "counted" : self.lastValue(),
            }
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)
        finally:
            logging.debug('Released getAsDict - %s', threading.current_thread().name)
            self.lock.release()

class Counters:
    
    def __init__(self,):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.store = {}
        
    def add(self, name : str) -> None:
        # add a counter object to the list:
        logging.debug('Waiting add - %s', threading.current_thread().name)
        self.lock.acquire()
        try:
            logging.debug('Acquired add - %s', threading.current_thread().name)
            self.store[name] = Counter(0)
        finally:
            logging.debug('Released add - %s', threading.current_thread().name)
            self.lock.release()
                    
    def remove(self, name : str) -> bool:
        # remove a counter from the dictionary:
        with self.lock:
            if name in self.store:
                del self.store[name]
                return True
            return False
    
    def get(self, name) -> Counter or None:
        with self.lock:
            return self.store.get(name, None)
    
    def getAll(self) -> dict:
        logging.debug('Waiting getAll - %s', threading.current_thread().name)
        self.lock.acquire()
        try:
            logging.debug('Acquired getAll - %s', threading.current_thread().name)
            ret = {}
            for name, counter in self.store.items():
                print(counter.getAsDict())
                ret[name] = counter.getAsDict()
            return ret
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        finally:
            logging.debug('Released getAll - %s', threading.current_thread().name)
            self.lock.release()
```

When I call the `getAll()` method I get stuck / deadlock in `lastValue`.
To my best knowledge python allows nested lock acquiring and in this case this is the problematic call path that causes the deadlock:

- getAll    (1 lock on Counters)
- getAsDict (2 lock on Counter)
- lastValue (3 lock on Counter) - Dead here

It can also be observed when running one thread:

```
def worker(c):
    for i in range(1):
        r = random.random()
        n = random.randint(1, 500)
        #random name:
        name = f"counter_{n}"
        logging.debug('Counter [%s] Sleeping %0.02f', name, r)
        time.sleep(r)
        c.add(name)
        c.get(name).increment()
    logging.debug('Done')
    result = c.getAll()
    logging.debug('Result: %r', result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    counters = Counters()
    for i in range(1):
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(counters,))
        t.start()

    logging.debug('Waiting for worker threads')
    main_thread = threading.current_thread()
    for t in threading.enumerate():
        if t is not main_thread:
            t.join()
```

The output is:

```
(MainThread) Waiting for worker threads
(Thread-7 (worker)) Counter [counter_129] Sleeping 0.55
(Thread-7 (worker)) Waiting add - Thread-7 (worker)
(Thread-7 (worker)) Acquired add - Thread-7 (worker)
(Thread-7 (worker)) Released add - Thread-7 (worker)
(Thread-7 (worker)) Waiting inc - Thread-7 (worker)
(Thread-7 (worker)) Acquired inc - Thread-7 (worker)
(Thread-7 (worker)) Released inc - Thread-7 (worker)
(Thread-7 (worker)) Done
(Thread-7 (worker)) Waiting getAll - Thread-7 (worker)
(Thread-7 (worker)) Acquired getAll - Thread-7 (worker)
(Thread-7 (worker)) Waiting getAsDict - Thread-7 (worker)
(Thread-7 (worker)) Acquired getAsDict - Thread-7 (worker)
(Thread-7 (worker)) Waiting lastValue - Thread-7 (worker) <-- DEADLOCK
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need a reentrant lock, `threading.RLock()`. With `threading.Lock()`, if a thread tries to acquire a lock it's already holding, it deadlocks.